# Normalizer of a proper subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying algebra using a lecture note based on Hungerford's algebra.
While I study p-group, I have below theorem

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$. Then $H \subsetneq N(H)$.

and as a corollary I have

> Any maximal subgroup of a p-group $G$ is normal.

But I think the above theorem may not be true. But if $G$ is a p-group then it is true.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $G$ must be a $p$-group for the first statement to be true. 
For an example when the statement is false when $G$ is not a $p$-group, you can take $G=S_3$ and $H=\{e, (1 2)\}$. Clearly $H$ is not normal in $G$. Since $\vert H\vert = 2$ and $\vert S_3\vert = 6$, we must have $N(H)=H$ (it is also easy to check this directly).

Just to be precise, in your first statement, $H$ must be a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ah, Yes. H must be proper. I wrote wrong symbol. Thank you!